# Is there a way to compare 2 unrebased git branches?

Tags: git, github

There is a branch `b1`. I created a new branch `b2` from `b1` (for backup). Now I have re-based `b1` over `master`. I also added some code while re-basing. Now I want to find the difference between `b1` and `b2` for only the files I changed, not the changes from the master branch. GitHub's compare feature is not working for me. Is there an option other than manually going through the changes?

Comment: "I also added some code while re-basing" What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

If your tree looks like this:

```
* H (feature-rebased) second commit of feature
* G first commit of feature
* F (main) third change to main
* E second change to main
* D first change to main
| * C (feature) second commit of feature
| * B first commit of feature
|/
* A (origin/main)
```

You can view the differences in your patches `feature` and `feature-rebased` via

```
git range-diff origin/main..feature main..feature-rebased
```

According to the `git range-diff` documentation, you can also use

```
git range-diff @{u} @{1} @
```

immediately after rebasing and resolving merge conflicts to compare the changes introduced by the rebase.